# Software to support live migration from physical to virtual, Windows 2008/R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, virtualization

I'm looking at trying to virtualize a few dedicated Windows 2008/2008R2 boxes, and am having issues finding a software solution that will support live migration.

I know that Norton Ghost 2.5.2 now *runs* in 2008/R2, but it doesn't support backing up that kind of environment.

Are there any production-ready solutions that will allow me to migrate dedicated hardware to a virtual environment (KVM) with as much uptime (live backup, migration) as possible? I know of a few offline solutions, but they are not an acceptable alternative.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment, the only [P2V tool for KVM virtual machine destinations](http://libguestfs.org/virt-v2v/) that I'm aware of only supports Linux source machines. So this is going to be a manual process with a few minutes more downtime than would be the case if a tool existed.